# How to set updating row's field with value of closest to it by date another field?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a huge table with 2m+ rows.
The structure is like that:

```
ThingName (STRING),
Date (DATE),
Value (INT64)
```

Sometimes `Value` is `null` and I need to fix it by setting it with **NOT NULL** `Value` of closest to it by `Date` row corresponding to `ThingName`...

And I am totally not SQL guy.

I tried to describe my task with this query (and simplified it a lot by using only previous dates (but actually I need to check future dates too)):

```
update my_tbl as SDP
set SDP.Value = (select SDPI.Value
    from my_tbl as SDPI
    where SDPI.Date < SDP.Date
    and SDP.ThingName = SDPI.ThingName
    and SDPI.Value is not null
    order by SDPI.Date desc limit 1)
where SDP.Value is null;
```

There I try to set updating row `Value` with one that I select from same table for same `ThingName` and with `limit 1` I leave only single result.

But query editor tell me this:
`Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.`

Actually, I am not sure at all that my task can be solved just with query.

So, can anyone help me? If this is impossible, then tell me this, if it possible, tell me what SQL constructions may help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

In many (if not most) cases you don't want to update your table (as it incur extra [cost](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#dml) and [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#data_manipulation_language_statements) associated with [DML statements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#limitations)) but rather can adjust 'missing' values in-query - like in below example:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  ThingName, 
  date, 
  IFNULL(value, 
    LAST_VALUE(value IGNORE NULLS) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY thingname ORDER BY date)
  ) AS value
FROM `project.dataset.my_tbl`
```

If for some reason you actually need to update the table - above statement will not help as DML's UPDATE does not allow use of analytic functions, so you need to use another approach. For example as below one

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  t1.ThingName, t1.date, 
  ARRAY_AGG(t2.Value IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY t2.date DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS value
FROM `project.dataset.my_tbl` AS t1
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.my_tbl` AS t2
ON t2.ThingName = t1.ThingName
AND t2.date <= t1.date
GROUP BY t1.ThingName, t1.date, t1.value
```

and now you can use it to update your table as in example below

```sql
#standardSQL
UPDATE `project.dataset.my_tbl` t
SET value = new_value
FROM (
  SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t1) AS id, 
    ARRAY_AGG(t2.Value IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY t2.date DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] new_value
  FROM `project.dataset.my_tbl` AS t1
  LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.my_tbl` AS t2
  ON t2.ThingName = t1.ThingName
  AND t2.date <= t1.date 
  GROUP BY id
)
WHERE TO_JSON_STRING(t) = id
```

Answer (score 3):

In BigQuery, `update`s are rather rare.  The logic you seem to want is:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(value,
                lag(value ignore nulls) over (partition by thingname order by date)
               ) as value
from my_tbl;
```

I don't really see a reason to save this back in the table.

Comment: Thank you. that's something too smart for me. trying to understand how this works O_o

Comment: @Kosmos . . . I recommend that you learn about `lag()` and other window functions.  They are quite useful.  The BQ documentation is a place to start although there are other resources available as well.